# Making a Discord bot with ts but im getting this error

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

Hello im trying to make a nick command for my discord bot but I have received this error.My bot is using type script.

Error:
Expression expected.ts (1109)

when i replace

> const mentionedMember = message? message.mentions.members?.first():

with

> const mentionedMember = message? message.mentions.members?.first(),

it fixes const nickName = args.slice(1).join(" "); but gives me the error

':' expected ts(1005) [19,76]

code:

```
import  "discord.js";
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";


export default{

    name: 'nickname',
    category: 'Moderation',
    aliases: ['nick'],
    description: 'Nicks a user',
   
    permissions: ['MANAGE_NICKNAMES'], 

    slash: 'both',
    testonly: true,

    callback: async({ client, message, args}) => {

        const mentionedMember = message? message.mentions.members?.first() : 
        
        const nickName = args.slice(1).join(" "); 
        //gets the nickname

        if (!args[0]) return message.reply('You did not mention a user for me to change there nickname!'); 
        if (!mentionedMember) return message.reply('Please mention a user for me to change there nickname \`>nickname @user nickname\`');
        if (!nickName) return message.reply('Please mention a nickname for me to change this users nickname');
        //returns an error message if there isn't a user mentioned or the new nick is not specified

        if (!mentionedMember.kickable) return message.reply('This User Has a senior rank then me i cant change his nickname') 
        //checks if the user that has been mentioned is below the bot in rank of roles, if not the bot won't be able to change the nickname
        
        await mentionedMember.setNickname(nickName) && await message.reply(`Successfuly Changed ${mentionedMember} Nickname to ${nickName}`); 
        //changes the nickname to the specified nickname and sends a message Successfuly
    
    },

}as ICommand
```

Comment: You did `? ` but it should have been `?.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to perform a ternary statement, which is a shorthand version of an if-else statement, denoted by ? and :, where ? is what should happen when the condition is true, and : is what should happen when the condition is false. For example:

```
message = (hasApplesauce) ? 'we have applesauce!' : 'no applesauce :(';
```

This code snippet will set message to "we have applesauce!" if hasApplesauce is true, and set it to "no applesauce :(" when the hasApplesauce boolean is false. The above statement is equivalent to this in normal if-else conditional code:

```
if (hasApplesauce)
{
    message = 'we have applesauce!';
}
else
{
   message = 'no applesauce :(';
}
```

You can replace that boolean with other conditional statements similar to any other if statement. The compiler is likely reading your message? on the error-causing line as the beginning of a ternary statement, which is why it wants you to add an equivalent : after it. If you are just trying to do a ? variable check, you want to change the line

```
const mentionedMember = message? message.mentions.members?.first() :
```

into

```
const mentionedMember = message?.mentions.members?.first();
```